# IE9 title bar showing only domain name not showing page title

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, title

I have web application , where will be navigating to different pages , but in IE9 only domain name showing.
Like when you google java and click search button will be getting the title bar as **java - Google** Search and https://google.co.in/#q=java

**But in IE9 for web application it is not showing tile( like java - Google) but showing domain name.
Its html page only.**

Can anyone please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the `<title>Title goes here</title>` tag in every page, in the `<head>` section?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. There [seems to be a bug in IE9](http://justin.morant.me/web-development/language/php/ie9-tabs-do-not-display-title-tags) where the title is not correctly shown (and `document.title` is not correctly populated) if the `<title>` tag is not the **first tag** right after the `<head>` tag.

**Solution 1:** The easiest solution is to simply move the `<title>` tag to the top of the `<head>`

**Solution 2:** If for whatever reason you cannot move the tag (e.g. it's generated automatically by a CMS), you can use the following JavaScript to populate `document.title` from the DOM:

```
/**
 * Fix IE9 title bug
 *
 * This is a workaround for bug where IE9 does not correctly populate document.title if the
 * <title> tag is not the first tag after the <head> tag.
 */
if (!document.title && typeof document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0] === 'object') {
    document.title = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code it will work in ie9
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they don't teach the solution.